# How to evenly divide flex box items into two rows?

Tags: css

I am having trouble dividing my flexbox into two rows. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I would use css selectors but the amount of flex items is dynamic

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: fit-content;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    background:red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Try **CSS-GRIDS**, that's more powerful and you need pretty less code as well :)

Setting 2 rows instead of 2 columns:)

```css
.flexbox {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:repeat(2,150px);
    grid-auto-flow: column; 
    column-gap:1rem;
    row-gap:10px;
}

.flex-item {   
    flex-basis: 280px;
    flex-shrink:none;
    height: 150px;
    background:red;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, there may be some confusion as I am trying to divide the flex items into two horizontal rows and currently your answer has 2 vertical columns

Comment: now it's similar (to not say the same) to the duplicate question

Comment: Ya Bro, you are right ! But I didn't want my answer to be wrong here and not what OP was not looking for :) Have to correct it and Reply back to OP :)

Comment: I didn't gey any request from you ...

Comment: I commented once actually :) May be you had not looked at :)

Comment: probabaly you didn't ping in the comment because if you don't do I don't get any notification (like 2 of your comments here)

Comment: Hmm :) Bro!  I have my last round of interview with a company on 20th, previous rounds have went good. Kindly share some best material on CSS-Grids and accesibility, and `Git` please (YOU HAVE GOT LOADS OF EXPERIENCE) . ReactJS part I managed well...

Comment: I don't have any specific material. I grab the information I want for the Specifications (w3.org/TR/?tag=css) and I do a lot of practise

Answer (score 0):

### **UPDATED:**

Set `flex-wrap:` to `wrap` and give `.flex-item` a `width` of `20%;`

Use this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/BaLqEdg

Comment: Dear Fellow Mate ! We didn't understood the question well:) I also thought that OP, wants two columns. When OP actually wanted two rows. Then OP commented and fixed it with CSS-Grids itself :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather So we got tricked . I to have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes dear ! That's why when OP commented... I quickly fixed it for him ;)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Are you preparing for an interview.

Comment: Yup Dear :) Friend !!!

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Did you left your job due to covid?

Comment: I moved during initial days of COVID. Had some plans, with didn't go well when COVID started to grow. I was working in Bangalore. Just came home.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I to want to work in Bangalore, but nobody will hire under 18. 